# How to get currently logged on username, domainname, and the users sid from a non administrator user?

Tags: c++, windows

Is it possible to get the currenlty logged on users username, domainname and SID, from a non administrator user? If yes, could someone provide me some example code, or the steps where should i start?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the name of the current user running some particular program which you want to add "get user's name, etc" to, or do you mean "List all users currently logged on to this machine"? I'm pretty sure the latter is not possible via the publicly available API's for security reasons.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I mean, i have an .exe, say myapp.exe. There is a an dministrator user logged in, let's say admin. But the myapp.exe will be started with run as, by a non admin user. In this fall is it possible to get who is logged on?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but C++ may not be the ideal language. Obviously, the "Users" tab on Task Manager can show this, so the information is available. sysinternals.com has a psloggedon tool, which probably does what you want. Which is written in C or C++, but I doubt they publish the source code (they don't for other tools they do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

1. Use [`ProcessIdToSessionId()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the Session ID that the process is running in.
2. Use [`WTSQuerySessionInformation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the username and domain associated with the session.
3. Use [`LookupAccountName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the domain user's SID.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectely, but insted of `LookupAccountSid` i had to use `LookupAccountName`.